# How to splice a certain item within another array

Tags: javascript

I receive something like this:

serverDocument.scheduledLines [

{
_id: 'd375d9f136d9aed8161e874b',
resourceId: '54cc874716368a9be973d0cb',
workOrderId: '53yc4SeHRErSaWZcr',

},
{
_id: '4136758377e2a0b89fcd15fb',
resourceId: '54cc874716368a9be973d0cb',
workOrderId: 't3cdTGDpxhm6sue5Z',

},
{
_id: '691cda0327a2b947bc40c008',
resourceId: '54cc874716368a9be973d0cb',
workOrderId: 'mzP5asqiMEKcYpPW9',

},]

I try to remove every **resourceId** element with serverDocument.scheduledLines.slice(0, 1), but in stead of removing the resourceId's, the second element is removed. Is it possible to remove the resourceId in one level deeper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just remove the property from each array item with a `map` function

```js
const array = [
    { _id: 'd375d9f136d9aed8161e874b', resourceId: '54cc874716368a9be973d0cb', workOrderId: '53yc4SeHRErSaWZcr',},
    { _id: '4136758377e2a0b89fcd15fb', resourceId: '54cc874716368a9be973d0cb', workOrderId: 't3cdTGDpxhm6sue5Z',},
    { _id: '691cda0327a2b947bc40c008', resourceId: '54cc874716368a9be973d0cb', workOrderId: 'mzP5asqiMEKcYpPW9',},
]

// removing the resourceId
array.map((item) => {
    delete item.resourceId;
    return item;
});

console.log(array);
```

Thats because in your attempt you don't manipulate the items in the array, you just manipulate the array itself.